# find variable length for sql server datatype nvarchar from c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

Can I find allowed variable length for nvarchar type in sql server 2008 from c# code in asp.net application?

For eg:

> nvarchar(?)

I want to find the maximum allowed number for "?" from c# code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this T-SQL query to look at the system catalog views:

```
SELECT 
    [max_length]
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('YourTableNameHere')
AND name = 'YourColumnNameHere'
```

This will return the stored, defined maximum length (in characters) for your column

**Update:** if you want to find out the max length of a **type** (not a column of any of your tables), you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT 
    name, max_length
FROM sys.types 
WHERE name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
```

**Be aware**: this returns the max length **in bytes** (not in characters!) so you get 8000 for both types. For `varchar`, 8000 bytes is equal to 8000 characters, while for `nvarchar`, 8000 bytes corresponds to 4000 characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.will above query give me the maximum allowed number for the "?" in nvarchar(?) in sql server 2008.   For eg: As i know,in sql server 2005,4000 is maximum allowed number for nvarchar i.e. for unicode and 8000 for non unicode.I want to find this allowed number i.e. 4000 or 8000, from c# code.

Comment: Thanks a lot and regards for this exact solution.

Comment: @swarraj: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

Please using TableSchema method for getting all details of column .

SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();

```
using (var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string ColumnName= row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
            string DataTypeName= row.Field<string>("DataTypeName");
            short NumericPrecision= row.Field<short>("NumericPrecision");
            short NumericScale= row.Field<short>("NumericScale");
            int ColumnSize= row.Field<int>("ColumnSize");
            Console.WriteLine("Column: {0} Type: {1} Precision: {2} Scale: {3} ColumnSize {4}",      
            ColumnName, DataTypeName, NumericPrecision, scale,ColumnSize);
        }
    }
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Size` property of the `SqlParameter`:

> For output parameters with a variable length type (nvarchar, for example), the size of the parameter defines the size of the buffer holding the output parameter. The output parameter can be truncated to a size specified with Size. For character types, the size specified with Size is in characters.

See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx).

---

If you mean from a database field, you can get the data with the `.GetSchemaTable()` method from the `DataReader` object. The `ColumnSize` attribute has the information you need.

Read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107) to see how to do it.