# Read Maximum length of Entity Framework field and assign to textbox in Razor View

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I want to map each field the user enters data into correlates with a database field that can easily set by reading database table definition and set it manually in razor view by setting maximum or in my view model but I need to make it dynamic if Database administrator change the maximum character limit through SQL server it will automatically update the maximum limit of character in text field.
I am trying to read it from Entity framework and set it in razor view. Is this possible to make it dynamic in any way.

And how can I read max length field from razor view.

Comment: DBAs shouldn't be arbitrarily changing the schema of an application's database without modifying the application itself - seems like a recipe for disaster. However, the answer in the following question will retrieve the attributes of an nvarchar field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611878/find-variable-length-for-sql-server-datatype-nvarchar-from-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further search I figure out how to read maximum length of field from Entity Framework Schema

```
public void read()
        {
            using (var db = new PortalContext())
            {
                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
                int maxLength = (int)container.EntitySets["Customers"].ElementType.Properties["LastName"].MaxLength;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Outstanding answer.  Provide context: namely, (1) that "PortalContext" should be replaced by the name of the entity model, inheriting from DbContext, and (2) that the names of the entity sets must match the db, not necessarily the names of the entities in the tables if their names have been singularized (eg, Customers to Customer).  Also, two usings are required:using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

Comment: FYI this is EF6 only. Not applicable to EF Core.